# Javascript match function not working in for loop

Tags: javascript

Javascript match function not working in my `for` loop properly. The match function works only once.
Not functioning code:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript' >
var numposts = 5;
function labelthumbs(json) {

    for (var i = 0; i < numposts; i++) {
        var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
        var posttitle = entry.title.$t;

            var postcontent = entry.content.$t;
            url = postcontent.match(/pname='(.+?)'/);

            if (url){
            document.write('<td>'+url[1]+'</td>');
            }else {

            document.write('<td> bb</td>');
            }
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.ibpsonline.in/feeds/posts/default/-/IBPS?published&alt=json-in-script&callback=labelthumbs"></script>
```

Comment: What do you want to match?

Comment: url = postcontent.match(/pname='(.+?)'/);

Comment: This is why I am asking *what* do you want to match; because I think you have written the match regex incorrectly.

Comment: first Loop works fine and coming to further not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work on all the post, however only one of the post has pname defined with `single quote`. You can change your regex to the check for double quote too like `postcontent.match(/pname=['"](.+?)['"]/i);`

```html
<script type = 'text/javascript' >
var numposts = 5;
function labelthumbs(json) {

    for (var i = 0; i < numposts; i++) {
        var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
        var posttitle = entry.title.$t;

            var postcontent = entry.content.$t;
            url = postcontent.match(/pname=['"](.+?)['"]/i);
            if (url){
            document.write('<td>'+url[1]+'</td>');
            }else {

            document.write('<td> bb</td>');
            }
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.ibpsonline.in/feeds/posts/default/-/IBPS?published&alt=json-in-script&callback=labelthumbs"></script>
```